# How to solve the ClassCastException caused by java generics

Tags: java

Most people are experiencing ClassCastException caused by java generics. Everyone knows that it is because of Java generic erasure, but how should we solve this problem?for example:

```
Map<Integer,Long> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1,0L);

// I know this way violates the java generic constraint.
String json = JSONUtils.toJSONString(map);
Map<Integer,Long> mapFromJson = JSONUtils.parseMap(json);

for(Long v : mapFromJson.values()){
     // will throw ClassCastException
     System.out.println(v);
}
```

There are too many java generic constraints, so I have to be careful when using it. Why doesn't java use a true generic like C++？

Comment: This seems more like a rant than a question.  What kind of post would you consider to be a valid answer here?  And I presume that by "true generic", you mean a C++ template class, with all the additional compiler overhead that requires.  Java really is an entirely different kind of language from C++.

Comment: "Why doesn't java use a true generic like C++？" - Java generics were retrofitted to the language (in Java 5).  That meant that template-based generics were not a practical option.  What is why.  (And complaining won't help ....)

Comment: You can solve the problem by not making assumptions about the type of the resulting map. Or by not using a library that allows you to make those assumptions.

Comment: Indeed the real cause for the class cast exceptions is that round-tripping through JSON ... using default bindings ... is giving a Map that contains values with different types to the original.  The JSON library did that.  Not Java generics.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem I am so sorry.I have been a java programmer for five years.I really like the simplicity of java. I have encountered too many problems with generic exceptions in the process of using generics. There are so many rules for java generics, which violates the simplicity of java. why doesn't java try to make generics better to meet the simplicity of java?

Comment: @Tom - See my first comment.  They couldn't do generics in the C++ way without **breaking** the language ... and 10+ years of enterprise customers' code.   For business reasons, Sun did not want to do that.  (And complaining about it won't help.  Because NOW we are talking about 20+ years of code!)

Comment: @Stephen C Thanks,I know  jdk must be compatible with older versions, but the container package did a lot of big changes after 1.5 but there was no optimization about generics, which was frustrating.

Comment: Those changes were carefully designed to be backwards compatible.  C++ style templates are not and cannot be backwards compatible.  A number of very smart people though long and hard about the different ways to add generics.  The erasure approach was the best that satisfied the overarching compatibility requirement.. (This is not an "optimization" issue.  It is about the fundamentals of the programming language.)  It may be frustrating ... but you can't rewrite history.

Comment: @Stephen C "History and computer technology" maybe is an interesting topic :-) .Historical influence is now and outside, perhaps history is now and in the future.interesting .......

Answer (score 1):

Thought there exists Java generic erasure,but we know what the generic is,so we can solve it like this with jackson.

```java
    @Test
    void 测试() {
        Map<Integer,Long> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1,0L);

        String json = null;
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(map.getClass(), Integer.class, Long.class);
        Map<Integer,Long> mapFromJson = null;
        try {
            mapFromJson = mapper.readValue(json,mapType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(Long v : mapFromJson.values()) {
            // will not throw ClassCastException
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
```

Maybe a better way since you can just copy the type:

```java
    @Test
    void 测试() {
        Map<Integer,Long> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1,0L);

        // I know this way violates the java generic constraint.
        String json = null;
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Map<Integer,Long> mapFromJson = null;
        try {
            mapFromJson = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<Integer,Long>>(){});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(Long v : mapFromJson.values()) {
            // will throw ClassCastException
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just love that method name :-)

Comment: Google Translate claims it means "test".  I'm actually disappointed.

Comment: thank for your answer.My question is so many rules for java generics, which violates the simplicity of java. why doesn't java try to make generics better to meet the simplicity of java?